# How to display user role

Tags: user-roles, author-template

How to display user role on author page.

I have created my own role (group) so I want to display the user role on below the post and on author list.

I have tried this code but not working as its calling current_user and its showing current user role in all authors profile

```
<?php 
    $user_roles = $current_user->roles;
    $user_role = array_shift($user_roles);

    if ($user_role == 'administrator') {
        echo 'Administrator';
    } elseif ($user_role == 'editor') {
        echo 'Editor';
    } elseif ($user_role == 'author') {
        echo 'Author';
    } elseif ($user_role == 'contributor') {
        echo 'Contributor';
    } elseif ($user_role == 'subscriber') {
        echo 'Subscriber';
    } else {
        echo '<strong>' . $user_role . '</strong>';
    }
?>
```

How can I alter this code to display user actual role and not the current user role.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change:

```
$user_roles = $current_user->roles;
```

with

```
$user = new WP_User( $user_id );
$user_roles = $user->roles;
```

and the $user_id should e the actual user id who's role you are trying to get.

**Update,**

Sorry i just read the author template part so try this:

```
//first get the current author whos page you are viewing
if(isset($_GET['author_name']))
        $curauth = get_user_by('slug', $author_name);
else
        $curauth = get_userdata(intval($author));
//then get the user object with roles
$user = new WP_User( $$curauth->ID );
$user_roles = $user->roles; 
....
```

Comment: its giving blank output. No error or not text

Comment: try `var_dump($user);` to see what your are getting

Comment: getting this output `object(WP_User)#349 (7) { ["data"]=> NULL ["ID"]=> int(0) ["caps"]=> array(0) { } ["cap_key"]=> NULL ["roles"]=> array(0) { } ["allcaps"]=> array(0) { } ["filter"]=> NULL }`

I am using name of the role if you see in my first code not any id so can that cause the issue?

Comment: @pixelngrain i updated my answer

Answer (score 3):

I assume you are trying to show the role of the post's Author and not the current user viewing the author page.

assuming you are inside the loop, do the following:

```
//get the post author's ID
$user_id = get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ); //assume we are in The Loop

$user_obj = get_userdata( $user_id );

if( !empty( $user_obj->roles ) ){
    foreach( $user_obj->roles as $role ){
        echo $role;
    }
}
```

or, if you only assign one role to each user/author, then you can do the following instead replacing the whole `foreach` block:

```
echo $user_obj->roles[0];
```